# Build succeeded for heroku app but running into "Application Error"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

When I checked the Heroku build logs, it showed this:

The requested API endpoint was not found. Are you using the right HTTP verb (i.e. `GET` vs. `POST`), and did you specify your intended version with the `Accept` header?

My app runs on React framework for front end, and I use the Firebase realtime database for my backend. The app runs fine on my local server but when I try to deploy on to Heroku I run into this error.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you didn't set the environment variables, thus the base url for your request might be invalid. You can set them in Settings tab of your heroku application, under the Config Vars section.